# Convolution by Fourier inversion

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis

Let $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by
$$
\varphi(x)=e ^ { - \frac {|x|^2 } { 2 } },
$$
Find $\varphi * \varphi$ by using Fourier transforms.

My attempt:
By Convolution theorem, we have
$$
\begin{array}{l}
F(\varphi * \psi)(\xi)=F(\varphi)(\xi) \cdot F(\psi)(\xi) \\
\Rightarrow \varphi * \psi(x)=F^{-1}(F(\varphi)(\xi) \cdot F(\psi)(\xi)) \\
\Rightarrow \varphi * \varphi(x)=\int_{\Bbb R^n} e^{2 \pi i x \cdot \xi} \cdot e^{-|\xi^2} d \xi \\
=\int_{\Bbb R^2} e^{\left(2\pi i ( x _ { 1 } \xi_ { 1 } + \cdots + x _ { n } \xi _ { n }) \ - (\xi _ { 1 } ^ { 2 } + \cdots +\xi_ { n } ^ { 2 } )\right)}d \xi
\end{array}
$$
Now how to proceed.

Comment: Express your function as a product of exponentials, each of them containing only one of the $\xi_i$ and then completing the squares to get some exponentials of the $x_i$ and a product of integrals, each of them equal $\sqrt{\pi}$.

Comment: Sir, I am not getting you...You are talking about the usage of Fubini's theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT

$\phi(x)=e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{2}}=e^{-\pi|\frac{x}{\sqrt{2\pi}}|^2}$

$\widehat{e^{-\pi|\frac{x}{\sqrt{2\pi}}|^2}}(\xi)=\sqrt{2\pi}e^{-\pi|\sqrt{2\pi}\xi|^2}=\sqrt{2\pi}e^{-2\pi^2|\xi|^2}$

So $\widehat{(\phi \ast \phi)}(\xi)=\hat{\phi}^2(\xi)=2\pi e^{-4\pi^2|\xi|^2}$

Now use the fact that $\widehat{e^{-\pi|x|^2}}(\xi)=e^{-\pi|\xi|^2}$  and the Fourier inversion and some appropriate change of variables to find the convolution.